# Multi-file config for Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

So, I have a Spring Boot application that is based on a plugin architecture, with its config properties, as you would expect, in an `application.yml`. Due to the fact that plugins may or may not be enabled however, I am keeping the config for each plugin in a separate file.

What's more, I would like to differentiate between these files (e.g. by naming them differently - preferably after the name of the plugin itself) and not have them all as `application.yml`.

I know that I can use `spring.config.name` to add the names of all the property files, depending on what plugin is enabled, but I would like a more dynamic approach.

For example, a `config` directory, with an `application.yml` and sub-folders named after each plugin - with a separate `application.yml` in each one...

Ideally, I would then just set `spring.config.location` to the path of the `config` folder and Spring would pick up all these files, by looking up in the sub-folders *recursively*.

So, my question to you, dear Spring experts, is: what magic dust do I have to sprinkle on my config to make this happen?

Is there any other approach you would recommend I take?

Comment: Try spring config server. It might helps

Comment: Will spring boot external config with directories help you. It is possible to specify a directory there.